# Serializer/Deserializer for Vavr objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, vavr

Hello Im trying to add vavr to my projet, right now Im struggling with proper serializaition of Vavr.List objects. Below is my controller:

```
import io.vavr.collection.List;

 @GetMapping(value = "/xxx")
    public List<EntityDeleted> getFile() {
        return List.of(new EntityDeleted(true),new EntityDeleted(true),new EntityDeleted(true),new EntityDeleted(true));
}
```

EntityDeleted is my custom object, List is Vavr collection as shown in import statement. The response Im getting in Postman is:

```
{
    "empty": false,
    "lazy": false,
    "async": false,
    "traversableAgain": true,
    "sequential": true,
    "singleValued": false,
    "distinct": false,
    "ordered": false,
    "orNull": {
        "deleted": true
    },
    "memoized": false
}
```

where I expect JSON list of my objects. Below is my config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PlomberApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PlomberApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper jacksonBuilder() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.registerModule(new VavrModule());
    }
}
```

and bit of pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vavr-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring Boot retrieves all instances of *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module* class and initializes *ObjectMapper* with them. There's no need for additional magic.

My dependencies are as follows (Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE):

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile group: 'io.vavr', name: 'vavr', version: '0.9.1'
    compile group: 'io.vavr', name: 'vavr-jackson', version: '0.9.1'
}
```

With application configurured like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BootvavrApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BootvavrApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Module vavrModule() {
        return new VavrModule();
    }
}
```

and controller mapped like this:

```
import io.vavr.collection.List;
@RestController
class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    List<String> testing() {
        return List.of("test", "test2");
    }
}
```

output is:

```
["test","test2"]
```

You can check the code out here: https://github.com/mihn/bootvavr

Comment: I have found the solution, I had @EnableWebMvc annotation in one of my config class which somehow override my config to mapper

Comment: Oh! That might do that. :)

Comment: Removing @EnableWebMvc somehow solved exactly the same problem for me also.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem in my WebFlux application. Removing `@EnableWebFlux` helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with SpringBoot, but it seems you should return the `VavrModule` object instead of the `ObjectMapper` in your `jacksonBuilder()` method.

I base myself on these links:

- https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/issues/1885#issuecomment-284037353
- https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#jackson-modules

Comment: tried @Bean
    public Module jacksonBuilder() {
        return new VavrModule();
    } but its not working. I assume something is overriding my Mapper..

Answer (score 1):

The `ObjectMapper` you register as a bean is just not the one being use to serialize into JSON, Spring MVC won't use it to as it's not what he is looking for.

To handle content for HTTP Spring MVC uses [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) and if he detects Jackson in the classpath a [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) will be autoconfigured if not specified.

In Spring Boot adding should be enough to register the custom MessageConverter:

```
@Bean  
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();   
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.registerModule(new VavrModule());

    // Spring MVC default Objectmapper configuration
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);

    jacksonConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);   
    return jacksonConverter;  
}
```

In a pure Spring MVC application you would have to had the following code in the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class:

```
@Bean  
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();   
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.registerModule(new VavrModule());

    // Spring MVC default Objectmapper configuration
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);

    jacksonConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);   
    return jacksonConverter;  
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters();
}
```

[Some Documentation about ObjectMapper in Spring MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

Hope it helped!

Comment: I've tried It also, but still getting the same result which is as in first post

Comment: Did you try to add @Primary in addition of the @Bean? And which version of Spring boot are you using?